# React routing does not load components on browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom` version 6 and node version 18.16.1. After installing `react-router-dom` and importing `BrowserRouter` as router, routes, and route, I am encountering an issue. I have included a code snippet below with the error message that I received at the terminal:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import RecommendedVideos from './RecommendedVideos';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/search'>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <div className='app-page'>
              <Sidebar />
              <RecommendedVideos />
            </div>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object`, this will install the library as a dependency and the message will go away

Comment: Thanks! it really helped, the message is no more. Can you also fix the router not loading components on screen?

Comment: Sure, you need to include the component you want to load on your route using the element prop on the <Route /> component. For example `<Route path='/' element={() => <div><h1>Hello world</h1></div>} />`

Comment: when i try to include any component using element prop, the following error displays on browser:

Comment: [div] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Comment: <Route path='/search' element={<Header/>} />.  I added my component, and the browser is showing a blank screen